# clearTimeout is not behaving as expected in React, any help please?

Tags: reactjs

I will go straight to the point.

I have a variable called **showForm**  `const [showForm, setShowForm] =useState(false);` I am controlling if I should show a form or not with it .

The form will also be shown after 20s using `setTimeout` and I initialise a `timeoutId` **(let timeoutId;)** variable on global scope to keep track of the setTimeout.

I have a useEffect hook with an if statement that checks the value of **showForm**

```
useEffect(()=>{

 if(showForm === false){
  timeoutId =  setTimeout(function () {
    setShowForm(true)
  }, 13000)
 }else{
   console.log("timeout cleared",timeoutId)
   clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
 },[showForm])
```

The problem is that even if I change the variable `showForm` to true the setTimeout still runs and doesn’t get cleared. the console.log() inside the else runs normally but somehow the setTimeout doesn't get cleared.

I am making a mistake in the logic here? I have spent so many hours that I cant think of the problem anymore...

Comment: You may have the wrong reference to the timeout. Can we see how you're declaring the `timeoutId`?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you do not need to have a global `timeoutId`. If all the `useEffect()` hook is tracking is `showForm`, you can return a [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) from the callback to clear the timer.

Comment: hi @DennisMartinez I am declaring it like this: let timeoutId;

Comment: @Calvin has a good recommendation. I'd check out the link they posted. You're most likely recreating the reference on every render which isn't ideal.

Comment: @Calvin had a look and returning a function that clears the setTimeout worked!. thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the variable with `var`, `let` or `const` in react. Global variable is not allowed:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
      let timeoutId
       ....
      return () => clearTimeout(timeouitId)
```

Returning a function that clears the timeoutId will clear the setTimeout. Note: the timeoutId has to be inside useEffect

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Bhojendra, in fact I am defining it with let, sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Show us where are you defining it. Define it in the useEffect scope itself and let's see what happens.